# Passing in 'This' keyword

Tags: java, this

```
public class CommandForm extends Form implements CommandListener {

    Display d;

    public CommandForm(String msg) {

        super(msg);
        this.addCommand(exit);

    }


    private void showMessage(String title, String text) {
        Alert a = new Alert(title, text, null, AlertType.INFO);
        d.setCurrent(a, this);

    }

    public void prepare_view(Display d){
        this.setCommandListener(this);
        this.d = d;
    }

    public void show_view(){
        d.setCurrent(this);
    }
}
```

I do not know exactly what the 'this' keyword means in this example. My lecturer says it is the current object, when I inquire further, he said it is the CommandForm. Is that correct? When you pass in 'this' into a parenthesis, e.g setCommandListener(this) are you actually passing the CommandForm? The only way I know how to use 'this' is like this way, this.d = d. So this is kinda new to me.

Answer (score 2):

Your lecturer is indeed correct. It's the current object, and `this` is simply a means to refer to the object currently in scope.

You use the keyword to pass the reference to other objects e.g. `object.doSomethingWith(this)`, and/or resolve ambiguity between members and variables (e.g. `this.x = x` - there are two different `x`s here).

Check out the [Java Language Specification section on 'this'](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3).

Answer (score 2):

He's right. If you call `setCommandListener(this)` you are passing a reference to the current object into the method. When you do `this.d = d` you are setting the variable `d` which is part of the class (i.e `this`) to the incoming value (in parenthesis).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `this` keyword is a reference to that particular instance of the `CommandForm` class.

Comment: No, it's a reference to this *instance* of the `CommandForm` class....

Comment: @Roddy - Good point. That is what I meant, but should be more clear. Edited.